# O(n) + O(n) = O(n)?

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

According to Alex Martelli in O'Reilly's Python in a Nutshell, the complexity class `O(n) + O(n) = O(n)`. So I believe it. But am confused. He explains it by saying that, "the sum of two linear functions of N is also a linear function of N."

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function), in functional analysis a linear function is a linear map, an example of which would be `f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)`. Found what seems to be a simpler definition [here](http://www.columbia.edu/itc/sipa/math/linear.html) simply stating, "a linear function is a function who's graph is a straight line." And it includes a few more examples that are less esoteric-looking than the wikipedia article ones.

```
y = f(x) = a + bx
```

and:

```
y = 25 + 5x

let x = 1
then
y = 25 + 5(1) = 30

let x = 3
then
y = 25 + 5(3) = 40
```

Maybe it would be fair to expect that the sum of two linear equations could be represented on a graph as a straight line which shows something similar to an *average* between the straight lines that would represent each one.

So am I understanding correctly that even though in the following two functions, the "complex" function takes three times as long to process as the "simple" one, they each function in big-O notation as O(n), because the arc of the processing time would be represented by a straight, diagonal line on a plot/graph, and the time difference would be represented by the fact that on a graphic representation, the angle of the more complex function would be sharper?

```
from timer import Timer

def complex(it):
    result = []
    for i in it:
        result.append(i)
    result.reverse()
    return result

def simple(it):
    result = list(it)

longlist = list(range(0, 1000000))

with Timer() as t:
    reverse_(longlist)
print "=> elapsed time reverse: %s." % t.secs

with Timer() as t:
    straight(longlist)
print "=> elapsed time straight: %s" % t.secs
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: AFAIK, big-o isn't too worried about precision at that scale. It's really used to compare things like O(n) vs O(log n) vs O(3^n), etc.

Comment: In Big-Oh analysis, you throw away constant leading coefficients and constants -- generally speaking.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The statement is correct, because the addition of two linear functions is also a linear function. Take for example these two:

```
y = 6*x + 10
y = 20*x + 2
```

Add them together and you get:

```
y = 26*x + 12
```

Which is also a linear function! This holds for any two linear functions.

```
y = A*x + B
y = C*x + D
-----------
y = (A+C)*x + (B+D)
```

Comment: thank you! I hope you don't mind me adding a link which shows a graph representation of the formulas.

Comment: Why are you adding the `y`s on the left-hand side of the equations?  You have to different linear functions `f_1(x) = a*x + b` and `f_2(x) = c*x + d`.  The sum of those two functions is `f(x) = f_1(x) + f_2(x) = (a + c)*x + (b + d)`.  The assumption that the `y`s on the left hand-side are the same for both functions is wrong, so it doesn't seem to make any sense to add them to `2*y`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach of course you're right. I'll edit it; doesn't affect the conclusion though.

Answer (score 17):

Correct, O(n) + O(n) = O(n).

More specifically, O(n) + O(n) = 2 * O(n), but since Big O only cares about functions as they tend toward infinity, anything linear is denoted as O(n).

Comment: ah. that clarifies it a bit further.

Answer (score 8):

> So even though in the following two functions, the "complex" function takes three times as long to process as the "simple" one, they each function in big-O notation as O(n), because the arc of the processing time would be represented by a straight, diagonal line on a plot/graph, even though the angle of the more complex function would be sharper?

Yes. The letter **O** is used because it refers to the order of a function. Linear functions are of the same **order**, `O(n)`, `O(3n)`, `O(Cn)` are all linear.

On the other hand, `O(n^2)`, `O(n^3)`, and `O(n^C)` are all polynomial functions (of degree 2, 3, C). Here (when dealing with algorithms), we often **do** start making a distinction between things like `O(n^2)` and `O(n^5)` -- even though they are both of the same order.

And `O(2^n)`, `O(3^n)`, and `O(C^n)` are exponential. You generally don't want to write an algorithm with exponential complexity (or worse).

Comment: I've been trying to understand what polynomial functions were so that helps. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

A good (the best?) way to go about it is to refer back to the mathematical definition of big-O:

[image]

In plain English:

> These two statements are equivalent:
>
> - ***f*** is ***O(g)***
> - The ratio of ***f(n)*** to ***g(n)*** as ***n*** increases tends to a nonnegative value.

In our case we have ***g(n) = n***. Now if we let ***f(n) = f<sub>1</sub>(n) + f<sub>2</sub>(n)*** and assume both ***f<sub>1</sub>*** and ***f<sub>2</sub>*** are *O(n)*, the limit above will equal ***α = α<sub>1</sub> + α<sub>2</sub>*** which itself must be greater than or equal to zero (since by definition ***α<sub>1</sub> ≥ 0*** and ***α<sub>2</sub> ≥ 0***). Therefore ***f<sub>1</sub>(n) + f<sub>2</sub>(n)*** is also *O(n)*, by our definition.

Comment: As such, `=` is definitely an abuse of notation.

Comment: @Rhymoid +1. It should be more like `O(f) = O(g)` to be on safe side with everything.

Comment: The statement with the Greek symbols is eluding me. I'm also not really understanding where the `g(x) = x` comes from. X is a value, right? Do we mean that the (value of the) result of g(x) = x?

Comment: @arshajii I think you need to drop the `n` from the first statement.

Comment: @Rhymoid Sorry, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @arshajii In the second statement, `n` is 'bound' or 'quantified' by `lim`, so it's clear what you mean by it. But in `f(n) \in O(g(n))`, the `n` has no clear meaning. `O(.)` takes a function and yields a set of functions; by `f(n)`, you actually just mean the function `f` (again, an abuse of notation ;)).

Comment: The new plain english translation of the statement contained in the image is much clearer now. But what exactly does `g` represent?

Comment: @MikeiLL The _g_ is simply what's inside the O. In your case that's _n_ since you're asking about _O(n)_.

Comment: Then why have a `g` at all not stick with n? And are we then saying `n(n) = n`, which is still totally confusing to me.

Comment: @MikeiLL Because the more general _g_ is required in the actual definition of big-O. _g_ is simply a function of _n_, and in this case _g(n) = n_ (again, because we're dealing with _O(n)_).

Comment: You mean `g is a function of n` like the way `__add__` is a function of `x` (a python variable)?

Comment: This should be "lim sup" instead of "lim".  The limit of f over g isn't required to exist.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is because Big-O notation is not meant to be used for the calculations of absolute running time, but to describe behaviour of algorithms with growing input.

In other words, if you have some algo that works in `O(3n)` and `O(n)` and you increase `n` however you want both of them will run as much longer.

It just gives a notion if one algorithms will out-scale another one at some point of increasing the input.

Of course mathematically everything can be proven using definitions.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say the first `O(n)` is represented by an equation:

```
y1 = f1(x) = a1 + b1.x
```

and the second  `O(n)` is represented by an equation:

```
y2 = f2(x) = a2 + b2.x
```

By adding the two sides,

```
y1 + y2 = f1(x) + f2(x) = (a1+a2) + (b1+b2).x
```

which shows that `y1+y2` is also `O(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

That's correct. So long as the line on the graph is a straight one, the function is O(n), regardless of the angle. A function takes linear time when you can say "this function takes x seconds for every input item." x in this case could be three, or nine, or a million, and it's still a linear function.

Answer (score 2):

Already there are a lot of good answers but I've not seen an answer from this angle. The sum of O(x) + O(y) is the worst of O(x) and O(y). in this case as both of them are linear, say `x = C1n` and `y = C2n` and C1 > C2. Thus x dominates the O() function and the big-O will be, `O(C1n) => O(n)`

Comment: I think that what you are saying is that whichever function represents the worst case scenario dictates the big_o status, right? Would you translate and/or give an example of `C1n` and `C2n`?

Comment: C1 and C2 are just 2 constants.